# Binding Polyline points to ObservableCollection doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, binding, collections, points, polyline

I'm stuck with binding the points of a polyline to an ObservableCollection(Of Point):

```
<UserControl
x:Class="GL.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="640" d:DesignWidth="840">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#ff444444">
    <Canvas Background="#333333" Width="800" Height="600">
        <Polyline x:Name="Linie" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="800" Height="600" Fill="Gray" Points="{Binding Punkte}">
        </Polyline>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Height="55" Name="tb" Foreground="White" FontSize="{Binding Path=TS}" Text="JUST A TEST!" />
    <Button Content="Add Point" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="745,617,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
</Grid>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl

    Dim r As New Random(345)
    Private _punkte As New ObservableCollection(Of Point)
    Public Property Punkte As ObservableCollection(Of Point)
        Get
            Return _punkte
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Point))
            _punkte = value
            SetValue(Punkte_DP, _punkte)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ts As Integer
    Public Property TS As Integer
        Get
            Return _ts
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _ts = value
            SetValue(TS_DP, _ts)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Punkte_DP As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Punkte", GetType(ObservableCollection(Of Point)), GetType(MainPage), New PropertyMetadata(New ObservableCollection(Of Point)))
    Public TS_DP As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TS", GetType(Integer), GetType(MainPage), New PropertyMetadata(New Integer))

    Public Sub New()

        Me.DataContext = Me
        InitializeComponent()

        Linie.DataContext = Me.Punkte
        Punkte.Add(New Point(100, 100))
        Punkte.Add(New Point(700, 300))

        TS = 25
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Punkte.Add(New Point(r.Next(0, 600), r.Next(0, 600)))
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run this, the FontSize gets updated but there's not a single point resp. line being drawn. The collection gets bigger each time the button is clicked, but nothing happens.

What the heck am I missing here? Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the points in the polygon are not updating is because the [`Polygon.Points`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon.points(v=vs.95).aspx) property takes a value of type [`PointCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection(v=vs.95).aspx), and that Silverlight is unable to convert an `ObservableCollection<Point>` to a `PointCollection` itself.

What you need to do is to add a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx) that converts from `ObservableCollection<Point>` to `PointCollection`.  Something like the following should do:

```
public class ObservableCollectionToPointCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var points = value as ObservableCollection<Point>;
        if (points == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var collection = new PointCollection();
        foreach (Point point in points)
        {
            collection.Add(point);
        }

        return collection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Not needed for one-way bindings.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As an exercise, I'll leave it for you to convert this to VB.NET.

To wire up this converter, add a namespace declaration such as

```
xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceContainingTheConverter"
```

to the root `<UserControl>` tag, add

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <myns:ObservableCollectionToPointCollectionConverter x:Key="converter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

after the end of this tag but before `<Grid>`, and modify the `Points` binding in your `Polygon` to

```
Points="{Binding Punkte, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
```

There were, however, a few other issues I encountered with your code.

Firstly, I got a few 'Value does not fall within expected range' errors when I first ran your code.  This turned out to be because [TextBlock.FontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize(v=vs.95).aspx) must have a positive value.  I moved the initialisation of `TS` to before the assignment to `Me.DataContext` and these errors went away.

Secondly, the line `Linie.DataContext = Me.Punkte` is wrong.  This sets the DataContext of the `Polygon` to your `ObservableCollection` of `Point`s.  The binding `{Binding Punkte}` in the Polygon's `Points` property tells Silverlight to look for the collection in a property named `Punkte` of the data context, i.e. the `ObservableCollection` of `Point`s.  This will fail as the `ObservableCollection` class has no property named `Punkte`.  This line should be deleted - the Polygon will inherit its data-context, which does have a property named `Punkte`, from its parent.

Thirdly, I replaced your use of dependency properties in MainPage.xaml.vb with 'ordinary' CLR properties, and made `MainPage` implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.95).aspx).  The properties then looked as follows:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Point> Punkte
    {
        get { return _punkte; }
        set
        {
            _punkte = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Punkte");
        }
    }

    public double TS
    {
        get { return _ts; }
        set
        {
            _ts = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("TS");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Again, feel free to convert this to VB.NET.

The final change I made was to add a call to `FirePropertyChanged("Punkte")` to the `Button1_Click` event handler.  This lets Silverlight know that the observable collection of points (and hence the converted PointCollection) has changed and must be updated by the UI.

Generally, using `ObservableCollection`s for collections in the view-model is enough to get change notification working.  However, in this case it doesn't work quite so well because the `ObservableCollection` is being converted into another object before being passed to the UI layer.  As a result, the `CollectionChanged` events fired by the `ObservableCollection` aren't being listened to.  This isn't a problem with your code as such, it's more of a limitation of the framework.  I did look to see whether it was possible to write a subclass of `PointCollection` that also implemented `INotifyCollectionChanged`, but this is impossible since `PointCollection` is `sealed`.

Instead of firing this event only for `Add`s, it may be better to handle the `ObservableCollection`'s `CollectionChanged` event in your `MainPage` class, and have this event handler call `FirePropertyChanged("Punkte")`.  That way, the polygon will keep up to date with all changes to the collection.